# Answer for a different version of language than the version used by the OP

Tags: discussion

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613940/javascript-overriding-tostring-prototype) question today. This asks a question about javascript prototypes.
then there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614017/3556874) answer.
The answer is really good, just that it targets ecma-script-6 standard which is not yet released, and the question is regarding ecma-script-5 but not really about ecma-script-6.

According to me the Answer is really useful for future users and those trying to learn ecma-script-6.

My question is what should I do in this case..

1. Should I add a tag `ecma-script-6` to the question so that this answer will be easy to find out for users searching `ecma-script-6` questions. But question doesn't seem to be anyhow related with `ecma-script-6`

   Or
2. Should I  simply flag this Answer as `not an answer`, I don't know but this answer is useful.

   Or
3. DownVote

   Or
4. Upvote

Comment: #2 is not a valid option.  Even if the answer doesn't answer the question as asked, it is an **attempt** to answer, so **Not an Answer** does not apply.

Comment: ok so  what to do in this case..

Comment: I don't know the technologies so I can't really advise on that.  But I don't see anything that says "ECMAScript" in the question, so why do you say it is about ECMAScript-5?

Comment: oh its javascript being currently used

Comment: The question doesn't say that it wants specifically version 5 answers. I don't see a problem here at all.

Comment: No.. it tells javascript.. currently what browsers support is ecma-script-5.. not 6.. it is not yet there in the world completely

Comment: Ok.. consider this example.. if someone asks me a question about html, I can answer with html5 also becoz it is general. and is being supported by each browser worldwide.. but I cant answer html-6 becoz it is not in any browser

Comment: @NaeemShaikh but the question does not ask for a specific version at all.  so really anything is valid.  You are looking at it from the a very time localized perspective.  When ecma-script-6 is released, then there would be no issue, right?

Comment: yes.. thats what i am asking.. shall i add a tag ecma-script 6 to it and upvote the answer

Comment: @NaeemShaikh no, don't retag because they you are localizing the question to a specific version that the original question did not ask for (you'd also invalidate the other answers that are based on the original question).  I think we're saying you don't need to do anything.  If you think it answers the question and it is a good answer, then upvote, if you don't then downvote.

Comment: @psubsee2003. ok then..

Comment: Most importantly, OP states it isn't fully supported yet: "there is no other way to do this *yet*." So everyone reading this will look if it is compatible. In a year, this would probably be the 'best' answer since all browsers support it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The specific case you present should not be flagged, as it is actually an answer, and don't retag the question as you suggest.

Upvotes and downvotes are yours to use as you see fit, according to your own standards of quality.

This being said, in my opinion it would be **a very poor decision to downvote the answer you linked to.** We don't write answers only for the absolute immediate need of the OP but also for future readers. The answerer referred to an earlier answer that dealt with the OP's immediate problem and added information that will eventually be useful to know.

Comment: yes.. got it.. louis

Comment: I appreciate answers that say "You can't do that yet, but it is planned in release X.X..." When X.X is released, someone might edit that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a comment thanking the answerer for the inciteful answer and promise to upvote after there's an answer that answers the question for today's browsers.

This means the question remains in the unanswered view on the main page.