# OpenCV interface/OS/legacy question handling

Tags: support

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a conglomerate of opensource libraries primarily used for image processing. These libraries are built and supported on many different OS and include multiple interfaces(C, C++, Java, Python). It is also periodically updated and new versions are released. So to provide an answer to a question which is tagged for say 'OpenCV v2.4.10 on Mac OS using Java', is it ideal or necessary to provide example source that matches any/all three of these categories?

For instance should I provide a good answer using my current setup (OpenCV v3.0.0 on Windows 8.1 using C++) to someone with the former setup? Or would my answer be too irrelevant or confusing to the question asker?

Comment: The API calls are the same for java/c++/python?

Comment: @rene For the most part yes.
Example: **imread**
Python: 'img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)'
Java:  'Mat img = Highgui.imread("messi5.jpg", 0);'
C++:  'Mat img = imread("messi5.jpg", 0);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i try to use it bat cnnot get to work in java alwys gives a huge error list

This comment pretty much tells you why you should not do this.  Both the OP and whomever is going to Google the question someday is only going to be interested in solutions in the tagged language.

Also pretty important to target your answer to the probably audience, [opencv] questions tend to be asked most often by students.  They inevitably struggle with the basics, like not recognizing that your snippet is written in C++ instead of Java.  Small steps are important to help them.

Comment: Would you favor two versions? One in win/c++ (that is what the OP uses) and then one that, maybe roughly, is translated to the platform asked for? That would benefit two types of visitors.

Comment: @rene: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303339 So if he hadn't asked for answers in a specific language, then answers in other languages would be useful. As-is, a clear no.