# I just got a tag badge for a language I don't even know

Tags: discussion

I got a bronze tag badge today for Objective-C even though I've never written a single Obj-C program in my life. I can guess my way through the meaning sometimes, but I certainly can't produce the syntax by myself.

The reason I got this badge is that I have added Swift version answers to old Objective-C questions. Examples:

- [How do I test if a string is empty in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c/31327086#31327086)
- [Cocoa Core Data efficient way to count entities!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-efficient-way-to-count-entities/32031611#32031611)
- [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/31934786#31934786)
- [iPhone popup menu like iPad popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769169/iphone-popup-menu-like-ipad-popover/32295907#32295907)

The issue of what to do with Swift vs Objective-C has been discussed several times before on Stack Overflow Meta without a clear consensus. I've written about it myself [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303483/3681880).

In the past, I used to start a whole new question for Swift. Example:

- [Swift: How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/swift-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel)

However, I do it less now because there seem to be quite a few high rep users who consider these duplicates. It attracts less negative attention to just add Swift answers to Objective-C questions. (I may be sorry for even giving the link above.)

I think the following actions would be beneficial:

- changing the tags (and possibly titles) on old Objective-C questions (to either remove the Objective-C tag or add a Swift tag)
- allowing more Swift versions (or "duplicates" as some people may call them) of Objective-C questions

One other option is to edit the Swift code into the accepted answer. However, there are two problems with this:

- making such a large edit could be perceived as stepping on the toes of the original answerer
- there is no rep benefit to doing so

Anyway, I just made this question to point out an interesting consequence of discouraging new Swift questions that have older Objective-C versions.

Comment: I have tag badges in Java and C#, too, and on Careers I think I am in the top 10% for those tags despite not having written a single line in those languages in my life. It's a consequence of being very active on SO, a real flaw in the system but likely not one that SE will treat as a priority.