# Is it a good practice to translate Objective-C answers to Swift?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I often see Stack Overflow answers which are written in Objective-C when I search stuff about iOS on Google.

Every time that happens, I really want to edit the answer to provide a Swift translation of the answer, but I'm not really sure whether it is good/allowed to do it. This action has the following advantages for people who have only learned Swift:

- it can help them to understand the answer
- it can help them to see how ObjC is translated to Swift, and hence, to get a basic idea of ObjC syntax

But I'm really not sure about this because making such a big change to an answer and not getting the OP's approval is bad (I think).

So I thought of an alternative - adding another answer. But that will probably go to the bottom of the page which makes it harder to see.

The translated answer will still keep the ObjC code. It just adds something like this

> Here is the Swift version:
>
> ```
> Blah.blah(blah, blah:blah)
> ```

Assume the translated Swift code is 100% correct and Swift-y enough.

Should I edit an answer to translate it to Swift? Why or why not?

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303338/are-new-swift-answers-on-old-objective-c-questions-beneficial). I'd say editing an existing answer is out of the question, as it changes the answer too much.

Comment: A new answer will go to the bottom, but may rise up over time. If many users have the problem in the question title, some of them _will_ be looking for a solution in Swift, and find your answer.

Comment: I see suggested edits add Swift solutions and I automatically reject them (obviously you're not suggesting now that you're 2k+). Just post your own answer, you might even get some rep for it.

Comment: @Barth but how should I phrase my answer? Just say 'this is the swift version of XXX's answer' doesn't seem like a complete answer. That's also why I thought of editing existing answers.

Comment: Also closely related: [Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions marked with the ObjC tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not edit your own code into someone else's answer. That counts as "attempt to reply". You're putting words into another user's mouth.

You could add your own answer. It will start at score 0, of course, but if the question is a common problem, other users will find it. Over time, your answer will rise.
Since your answer is a translation of someone else's code, it is appropriate to give attribution - as you observed in the comments.
How you phrase the attribution requires a little thinking. If you start with "this is a translation of ....'s code", it may be seen as a comment or rep-farming, and be flagged or downvoted. You'll want to show that there is some original work here. (There is, right? We don't need the translation if it's trivial!)
One way of phrasing this would be "Based upon ...'s answer, this is how to do it in Swift". Then explain a little about where the Swift version is necessarily different from the Objective-C version. Like, why a particular Objective-C construct had to be replaced with something different in Swift.

The question might specifically ask for a solution in Objective-C. In that case, you could create a self-answered question for the Swift version.

Comment: I think it would also be acceptable and helpful to add a comment to the Objective-C answer that contains a link to the alternative Swift answer.

Comment: This leads to spammy Swift 1, Swift 2, Swift 3, Swift 4, Swift 5 answers.

Answer (score 8):

Only ever add an answer using $language if the question isn't specific to some $other_language. The vast majority of questions at least look language-specific, though they might not actually be. Be wary when changing a question, especially if it is answered.

Unless an answer is marked community-wiki, you may not add your own original content in an edit:
 Doing so would be a radical change, post your own complete answer instead and get full credit and blame.