# Suggested Edits that Add Swift 3 Code

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, I frequently come across edits that only add Swift 3 code to answers that contain Swift 2 [(example)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14065668). Per [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336625/how-to-add-swift-answers-to-older-ios-questions), it seems the best way to update questions with new Swift syntax is to add a new answer rather than editing the existing accepted one. So just to clarify, should I be rejecting all of these suggested edits? If so, should the reason be "clearly conflicts with the author's intent?". This practice is so prevalent that I feel it needs clarification.

Comment: Although it may not be officially sanctioned, I am very grateful whenever someone updates my Swift 2 code to Swift 3. I've tried going though and updating it myself, but it is just too much work to do alone.

Comment: @Suragch But Swift 2 answers are not obsolete - some people still need them, and will continue to need them. :) And they will have historical value anyway. Users should not *replace* code in Swift 2 with code in Swift 3, that's never acceptable IMO. They should *add* a Swift 3 version - and *preferably in their own post, since they could be posting a bad/inaccurate update* and that would change the nature of the original question (I've already seen many people posting "update to swift 3" stuff that is pure nonsense or full of errors, added to a previously good Swift 2 answer).

Comment: @EricAya where Suragch says that "users should replace code"?

Comment: @Braiam "I am very grateful whenever someone updates my Swift 2 code to Swift 3" ... It is often a replacement instead of an addition.

Comment: @EricAya so, post shouldn't be updated ever? That's ridiculous and against core philosophy of the site "To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**" Nobody is talking about replacing, but updating. Even OP uses the term "**add** Swift 3 code"

Comment: @Braiam Sure. But even updating without replacing is often a problem. As I said in my previous comment, I have seen many "updates" that are actually just crap. **This**, adding garbage to an existing good answer, goes against the core values of the site. Good updates are rare (in my tags anyway). So yeah, I often disagree with "add updates as the post ages" because most of the times it's done in a wrong way. If there's a new way to answer the question, it should be posted in its own answer. In my opinion...

Comment: @EricAya then deal with those edits, but don't bar all possible edits because few bad ones. Editing is encouraged! If you see a crap edit being applied roll it back, but if you see a good edit being applied, laud it. Is not necessary to issue blanket statements.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. An edit should [**hardly ever** *correct* code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/4751173) inside an answer. Putting new blocks of code into an answer is a clear no-no. It doesn't really matter which reason you pick to reject, but "clearly conflicts with the author's intent" seems the best match. The author intended to write a Swift 2 version, not a Swift 3 version (even if that version didn't exist at the time).

Comment: This goes against a [core ideology](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) SE as built on: *When should I edit posts? *Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, *you are welcome to do so.** Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include: [...] **To include additional information only found in comments**, [...] **To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages*** Don't give anti-editing counsel, editing is explicitly encouraged!

Comment: Problematic. The result will be good answers become less useful. Sure that is what has always happened with textbooks but we could change that. What's the incentive to contributors to write new answers to questions with already-accepted answers? Seems like the gamification motive is gone at that point.

Answer (score -1):

> So just to clarify, should I be rejecting all of these suggested edits?

Not necessarily. There's nothing on the help center that prohibits you from editing answers, specially if it updates with new relevant information that solves the problem and improves the post, more so in walled garden environment like iOS, where if you don't use the latest supported language you are basically unable to reach all the potential public due constrains of Apple's review system. Rejecting changes just because they are new information is a disservice for the site and the editor might not even be aware that he can post a new answer (which have by default less exposure).

Now, there's a saying that "you shouldn't put words into OP mouth", but the reality is that OP is always notified of any edit on answers. *Always*. If you are not sure if the edit is correct, you may choose to skip an leave OP deal with it.

Recommended read:

## [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575)