# Suggested edits for Swift language updates (Swift 2.2, 3, etc.)

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've been running across a lot of suggested edits lately like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15147804) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14745705), where the edit changes an answer's Swift code excerpts.

The editor usually comments that they are updating the answer for a newer version of Swift, either replacing the code excerpt completely, or adding entirely new excerpts of code for each version.

Should these kind of edits be approved?

I've typically rejected these code edits, because they are substantial changes to code in the accepted answer, and without validating them manually myself I can't be sure they are even working excerpts of code.

### Example Suggested Edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15147804
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14745705

Comment: I also just saw a similar question is asked here (with no accepted answer) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336746/suggested-edits-that-add-swift-3-code, so this might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You should reject these.  The user is free to post their own new answer if they would like to provide an additional solution to the problem.  Editing someone else's answer into the answer you would have preferred is not appropriate.

Comment: After the question got migrated (totally forgot there is a separate meta for SO), I saw a similar question has been asked here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336746/suggested-edits-that-add-swift-3-code, but the answers look conflicted