# Add documentation-style language version tags to code blocks

Tags: feature-request

In documentation you can nicely format required versions at the top of blocks of code, *e.g.*

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte 2.7] -->
# Some code goes here
<!-- end version if -->
```

gives a nicely formatted `Python 2.x >= 2.7` at the top of the code block. It would be good if this could also be done in Q&A on Stack Overflow.

This might help with issues such as [those raised in this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348295/when-is-it-permissible-to-update-other-peoples-answers-for-python-3). While Python is a clear example of a use-case, I could also see it being useful in other situations where many versions are in concurrent use such as Fortran or C++.

Arguably this should be covered by appropriate tagging of the question with version numbers, but many questions are not posed perfectly and an extra visual aid for people scanning the answers later seems helpful.