# Changing the emphasis of python answers from python 2 to python 3

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Frequently, I come across an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr?rq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists?rq=1), for example where the answer is written with python 2 in mind, and python 3 edited in as an afterthought.

I don't think the python 2 should be removed from answers, but the emphasis should be changed so that the first exposition of the code is python 3.

My reasons:

- Python 2 will very shortly become unsupported. New users writing python for the first time will come across old code and may not yet know the difference between python 2 and 3. Having python 2 first indicates it is the preferred or most used version.
- Trying the first answer should more often than not give the desired result. If someone's trying to learn a new topic, they don't want Python 2/3 differences getting in the way. Python 2 should be a "by the way, this is how we used to it" for people who are stuck on legacy code or interested in the evolution of the language. These people will be used to understanding the differences and know what they're looking for.
- When python 3 equivalent code has been edited in after the fact, it adds confusion to have extra blocks with something such as "in python 3, just omit `object`" or "in python 3, the `if` block can be removed"; why can I remove it? which `if` block? This is mess that should be handled by people stuck on python 2, not everyone else who's using python 3.
- Sometimes the info to change from python 2 to 3 is added as a comment which may very well go unread.
- Some differences are hard to notice and might not be picked up at first, creating confusing errors. (integer division, unicode, etc)
- Certain changes from python 2 to 3 greatly improved readability, making it easier to interpret as a new coder. Again, this makes grasping new concepts easier.

```
# python 2
print 'hello %s %s' % (forename, surname)
# python 3
print(f'hello {forename} {surname}')

# python 2
class MyClass(BaseClass):
    __metaclass__ = SomeMeta
# python 3
class MyClass(BaseClass, metaclass=SomeMeta):
    pass
```

It seems odd that this hasn't been done already. Questions tend to follow python's style guide PEP8, clean, up-to-date code is obviously encouraged, but python 2 is everywhere in old answers.

So, is it OK to flip the emphasis on these old questions and answers? Interested to hear people's thoughts on the matter; I suspect a lot of you will just think this isn't important at all!

Comment: I wouldn't support an effort that consists of going through a ton of old content and updating/reorganizing code sections, it would be better to instead allow new questions to arise to replace them with python 3 answers as it gains more momentum.

Comment: This will happen naturally over time without intervention from us. As Python 2 usage begins to decline and more developers transition over to 3, so will answers consisting of it. _(Caveat: - unless the question specifically mentions Python 3)_

Comment: I agree to a point, but a lot of common questions get directed to the same old questions which will forever have the python 2 emphasis.

Comment: Also, Python 3 has been the preferred version for years now and this natural progression has not occurred.

Comment: I agree. While Python 2 and other languages that don't have support are still used and learned, and many applications will depend on Python-2 specific answers, I wouldn't say _encouraging_ answers to be Python 3 if py2 is not specified doesn't make sense

Comment: Okay, while I might be able to get behind the _why_, **how** do you think this should be done?

Comment: Should it also apply to other languages like C++ and Javascript? It's a lot of effort for a questionable gain.

Comment: @Lewis A lot of the "famous" answers which I refer to are protected, or edits which change emphasis are discouraged or rolled back. This could change.

Comment: Learning to deal with language version changes is something every developer who lasts longer than a few minutes is going to have to deal with. It's time to stop hiding from that fact. Every developer is going to have to learn to deal with old documentation and websites that are not updated (SO is not the only site on the internet). Being able to adjust to changes in how things work is part of the job. When I started in web development, `document.layers` was how you did "DHTML". Now I use npm to manage multiple layers of dependencies in my ECMAScript modules. Embrace the madness ;).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Good point. In Ancient Times, I tried to enumerate the number of different versions of Basic that I had ever used; I lost count around 20. :) There are some pretty big changes between Python 2 and Python 3, so it's more like a change of dialect than a simple version change. It's not that hard for the seasoned coder to deal with the switch, but the OP does have a valid point in that it *can* create confusion for the student learning their first language. That's significant because many schools are using Python as an intro language.

Comment: It should be remembered that python 2 has been around since 2000 and while support is ending in January 2020 there is still a release scheduled for April 2020. If you have been running a large python 2 app since the turn of the century there could be reasons why you are still going to use it after the end of support and will need answers based on it.

Comment: About two years back, I was stuck working on a machine that only had Python 2, and the system administrator refused to add Python 3 for some dumb reasons. Knowing the state of that product, I bet they're not going to make any change even when Python 2 is no longer supported, so anyone stuck on that machine will still be asking Python 2 questions long after 2020 comes and goes.

Comment: @DavyM I wonder if they realise that if a security vulnerability is discovered in Python 2 after the final release there will not be any official security patches made for it...

Comment: @PM2Ring "IF that ever happens, we'll deal with it then". That's the trouble with IFs, they're not real yet and thus pretty much invisible. Fast-forward a few years later, a security hole is actively abused and it's time for heads to roll. The very same person will then say "How could you have let this happen!?" <-- the dark side of the IT.

Comment: @Gimby Indeed! Mind you, I don't expect Python 2 to have hidden security flaws, but with that much code, nobody can be certain. It took years before [ShellShock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) was discovered in Bash (by Stéphane Chazelas from Unix & Linux Stack Exchange), and Bash is a lot smaller than Python 2.

Comment: The canonical may be *[When is it permissible to update other people's answers for Python 3?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348295/)*

Answer (score 9):

> It seems odd that this hasn't been done already.

It's a *huge* task. There are over 1.26 million questions with the generic Python tag, and many thousands more Python questions that don't have the generic tag; they just have version-specific tags, or tags of major libraries like Numpy, Pandas, Django, etc. Of course, many of the questions and answers from recent years are already suitable for Python 3, but to update everything properly for Python 3 is a *lot* of work.

In the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) it has been our policy for several years (since around Python 3.5 or so) to consider Python 3 as the default version if the question doesn't mention a version, and to encourage both question askers and answerers to update to Python 3 when we see Python 2 material posted.

But we're just a small chat room and we can't possibly keep up with the veritable torrent new of Python questions, our curate every existing question in the system. So we concentrate our efforts on the more popular questions, especially those that have been used as duplicate targets, or which look like they will make good targets in the future. We often discover these questions while searching for dupe targets.

When prominent questions or answers that need updating to Python 3 our found we encourage people to perform such updates, and that may involve having a discussion as to the best course of action. Sometimes, a small edit or two is adequate, but we do *not* want to invalidate any existing answers, or make edits that would radically conflict with the author's intention. Sometimes completely new answers need to be written, and as you can imagine it's hard for such answers to be visible when existing answers have scores in the hundreds or even thousands.

Some people would like to purge Python 2 from the system, but that's neither practical nor desirable. Unfortunately, Python 2 will continue to be used for several years in legacy systems.

---

The main thrust of your question asks: should we modify answers to give Python 3 more prominence than Python 2? In some cases, that's easy to achieve, but in other cases it requires changing not only the existing answer, but also the question, otherwise the answer can actually become *harder* to follow. And if you change the question you may need to change *all* the answers, not just the prominent ones, otherwise those other answers make less sense, or even become invalid.

Doing these things properly, without conflicting with the original intentions of the authors is difficult, to say the least. So I am not a big fan of your scheme.

---

However, if you wish to discuss these issues and co-ordinate your efforts with others, please feel free to visit the chat room.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. So, if changing emphasis (not removing python 2) in answers has no knock on effects, is it ok for me to edit them? Or is it just preferred to write a new answer, even on questions which already have many answers?

Comment: @QuantumChris Sure, if you can make changes like that in a benign way, please do so. If you're not 100% confident about modifying a post, please come to the Python room and we can discuss it. Quite a few of the room regulars have a lot of rep from answering Python questions, so we collectively have a fair bit of knowledge about Python itself, and the general state of SO's collection of Python questions (to the degree that that's humanly possible ;)).

Comment: @QuantumChris We also have several gold badge holders, which comes in handy for closing (or opening) dupes & editing dupe lists. And we have a small collection of common duplicates and canonical Q&As, which can be useful when you're looking for dupe targets. As I'm sure you've noticed there are a lot of dupes that have been closed with old Python 2 answers that are no longer ideal. We're slowly finding (or creating) better targets for them.