# Is it not ok to update posts with standardization information?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, edits, answers, specific-edit

Today I updated [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9838879/10147399) answer. It is a good answer that mentions use of a function from a  popular library. Some of the most useful parts of this particular library tends to get standardized into the language standard library itself, which is a good thing since you no longer have to take on a dependency to use the facility.

It turns out that the function mentioned in this answer was standardized recently, so I updated the answer to mention that, but my edit was rolled back by a moderator. My edit points out that the standard facility is now available, and the library alternative still stands.

Is this considered changing the intention of the original poster? What is the recommended action instead of editing?

Comment: Yeah, that edit seems entirely reasonable.  Don't know why it was rolled back.  Perhaps the edit was flagged; the C++ community has a reputation for being... very particular in the way things are done.  Common sense would seem to indicate that old posts should be allowed to be updated with more up-to-date, more accurate information.

Comment: Have you already flagged this question for mod attention asking the involved mod read this question? I think that only them are able to answer why it was rolled back. Maybe the problem was how the edit was done  (maybe splitting the answer in sections, keeping one for the old way and put the new way in another section)

Comment: @Rubén I've added a comment tagging the moderator asking for clarification, but I am not sure if flagging and getting all moderators involved is a great idea.

Comment: The mods are the ones who have the final say, so you might as well ask them directly.  They're not obliged to answer, however.

Comment: Adding a comment tagging the user who rolled back an edit is something that will throw a global inbox notification... I assumed that some SO mods will have a lot of that and at this time the inbox isn't very helpful for tracking "mods attention requests". Mods have other tools and if a mention of a specific mod is done in the custom reason I think that it's enough to address that flag to the corresponing mod.

Comment: @Rubén I raised a flag linking to this post with a small explanation.

Comment: Seems like enforcement of the "concensus" that interprets "authors intent" in the most asinine fashion. "SO is part-wiki" no more.

Comment: "Authorial intent" is an unfortunately ambiguous and unworthy ideal to uphold. Far better ideals would be maximal clarity, correctness, and utility for the reader. [*'"To give a text an author" and assign a single, corresponding interpretation to it "is to impose a limit on that text"'.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Author#Content) Sometimes, that limit actively inhibits improvement.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You'd think so, [but](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421310/are-edits-from-python-2s-print-to-python-3s-print-acceptable) the community seems to have quite a bit of difficulty agreeing about this sort of thing.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it never was "part wiki" by that standard; it only claims to be. It's notable here that wikis generally don't have in-line attribution of text in the article content; you have to look behind the scenes to have any idea who's involved.

Comment: I'd comment the answer, and if the user doesn't react (and decide for instance to edit the answer with that new info), I'd post a new answer. Linking to the "initial one", and saying in your case, that since version X, that function is "standard", or that's the "new way to deal with the issue". Keeping the infos (for users with lower versions) is important, and you did it in your edit, but I wouldn't go about improving another answer, since it wasn't its initial intention/decision.

Comment: @Larme I think it is more reasonable to update old answers, instead of adding new ones as "addendum". It is a better experience to have a single, high quality answer than having to track a number of updates, don't you think?

Comment: It IS C++ and C++ is a language pretty heavily dictated by version. Older C++ (spec) versions stay relevant for a long time, possibly forever. I don't find it unreasonable that in the arena of C++, it is more closely guarded to not let the new seep into the old.

Comment: @Gimby Please see my edit. It leaves the library alternative in place for older versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree with that edit being rolled back.

The edit was useful and correct, and it *improved* the answer. These are exactly the types of edits that we want users with subject-matter expertise to make, albeit while exercising all due caution.

In this particular case, there is not even a plausible argument that the edit is inconsistent with the author's intent. Boost is a staging ground for things that may later be added into the standard library. By recommending to use Boost when there's nothing in the standard library, the author of the answer recommended something *pseudo*-standard. It stands to reason that once it actually becomes standard, they'd recommend using that instead of the Boost implementation.

Of course, I would very much dislike if the edit *removed* the original, pre-C++17 solution, since that's still useful to many people, but it didn't, so there's no objection on those grounds, either.

There *might* be an argument to be made against such an edit if the question were explicitly tagged with a particular C++ language version (e.g., [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).  However, it is not. In fact, it is a general-reference FAQ. Keeping it up to date is something we can only dream of, and yet, you've done it; thank you.

Given the above, I've rolled back the rollback (and made a couple of minor grammar tweaks on top of it).

(For what it's worth, your edit wasn't flagged to request that it be rolled back, either by the answer's author or anyone else. The speculation in the comments about the C++ community being "very particular" has no basis in fact. This is, in my experience, *precisely* the kind of useful, correct edit that SO's C++ community would endorse, a sentiment that [StoryTeller evidently agrees with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421329/is-it-not-ok-to-update-posts-with-standardization-information#comment932955_421329), himself a prominent member of said community.)