# What to do with edits to questions that make changes for a more recent version of the technology

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've seen a number of questions in the review queues, where someone has updated a question to reflect changes in one of the technologies used. For example, the case I've just seen is someone changing an old code snippet to work in Swift 3.0.

It seems there are two things that people do:

1. Add a separate code block, like this one:
   [image]
2. Just change the code so that it works with the latest:

[image]

The first seems better because it doesn't risk taking away information that the original answerer gave. But I think a new answer is still probably more appropriate. Are there guidelines on this?

Comment: FWIW, [this similar edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14747511), which you voted to reject, was just approved by the author of the post

Comment: @TinyGiant That edit is of the first kind, so it would be one where I would also be OK with approving it. But you can't always ask the author what he wants, and this one case doesn't mean it should be applied as a rule. I think I'm leaning towards rejecting type 2 (and suggesting they leave another answer), and accepting type 1 if they don't need to duplicate too much code. What do you think?

Comment: So, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14747464) I think can be rejected because it conflicts with the author's original intent. Although.. the author _does_ state 1.6 and the edit links to documentation that says author's original code was deprecated in 1.5.10 and won't work in 1.6. Still, I think this is better as a comment.

Comment: Edits to _questions_, or edits to _answers_?  (This question's title doesn't seem to match its body.)

Comment: That's why I said "FWIW" (for what it's worth). See also: [Are edits that insert Swift 3 code into existing Swift 2 answers acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339024/4639281) That seems to indicate consensus towards rejection of both examples, if the edit comment on the second is correct.

Comment: Thanks, that discussions is useful.