# Edit rejected for not making post accurate; it does

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I am a fairly new user to Stack Overflow, so forgive me if this is too specific to be posted on meta. If it is, I'll gladly remove it.

I recently made a [fairly small edit to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14756615) since it inaccurately said that `base64` encoding uses only alphanumeric characters, when it also uses '+', '/', and '=':

> `base64` encoding takes 8-bit binary byte data and encodes it using only the characters A-Z, a-z and 0-9, so it...

This is a fairly small error, but is objectively incorrect and could cause users to leave with false information about `base64` encoding. I edited it just to make it correct so we wouldn't be putting incorrect information out there.

It was rejected with the reason: "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

I think it does clearly make the post more accurate. I ended up [answering the question myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/base64-encoding-in-python-3/41437531#41437531), but it seems like an edit really should have been all that was needed to ensure the current accepted answer (which will likely remain that way) was more accurate.

To the point:

- Is this a reasonable channel to express this thinking? (I figured posting here on the meta would make sense but I don't know if this site is meant to be more general rather than specific cases)
- Does my reasoning make sense, or have I misunderstood something about the process of editing existing answers?

Comment: No, this change was reasonable, and two knowledgeable people approved it. Sadly, there are just a bunch of reviewers who don't know what they're doing and should have hit "skip" instead of "reject".

Comment: @CodyGray Then what about the rejection reason which rejects the edits which are like this e.g. improving the mistakes in the post? "This is an attempt to reply and should have been a comment instead"? It should have been a critique comment, not an edit into the post. If the OP chooses to incorporate it into his answer with credits to Greg, that's his choice.

Comment: @nsnoob Fixing an obvious error in a post is not an attempt to comment. That rejection reason is for when someone tries to edit in a comment. Greg's edit ***absolutely*** should not have been rejected. It wasn't intended to address the author of the post, and it obviously makes sense as an edit. Thus, your proposed rejection reason is equally invalid. It makes no sense for Greg to have to write up an entire answer just to clarify that base64 encoding also includes other non-alphanumeric characters, and it is a waste of everyone's time for him to leave a comment and make someone else fix it.

Comment: *"How do we stop SO from turning into Documentation?"* I don't know what you mean by that. Q&A existed first, long before Documentation was ever introduced. The way I interpret that is, how do we stop Q&A from becoming a race to the bottom, with horribly inaccurate content, like Documentation contains. And the answer to that is, of course, community auditing and editing. If you mean, how do we stop the community from fixing simple technical errors in answers, well, I don't know what to say. This is not something that we want to stop.

Comment: Wildly upvoted comments are not necessarily a good thing. It is a problem when the post contains a technical inaccuracy that is only pointed out in the comments, since lots of people don't bother to read the comments (and shouldn't be expected to). An answer with a comment on it pointing out an inaccuracy is a problem, an edit waiting to happen. We aren't here to teach OPs how to rectify their mistakes. We are here to create a library of useful programming Q&A.

Comment: The question you linked seems to be agreeing that, while there are bone-headed reviewers that make the wrong decision, fixing technical problems is generally the right thing to do. The edit under discussion there was ultimately reapplied by a user with editing privileges, and everyone seems to be in agreement with this. Please don't be one of those bone-headed reviewers. If you aren't sure whether an edit is a good one or not, then click "Skip". Let someone who knows make the decision. @nsnoob

Comment: Yes that's what I meant with people trying to vandalize perfectly good questions with wrong/flawed info as in Documentation. In any case, I concede, you have a fair point :) I have previously rejected such edits without giving them a second thought, guess now I will have to consider them. Will be removing comments now.

Comment: @CodyGray Just to be clear, this is only for correcting technical inaccuricies? Or is it valid for edits which add further info to the post? Such as someone adding a Objective C version to a Swift answer on an iOS post? Or someone mentioning the risks in the suggested approach and proposing a way to avoid them?

Comment: It is a judgment call, that's why we have the Skip button. Probably editing in unrelated code for a different language is going too far (we've had discussions specifically about this with Obj-C and Swift on Meta; use the search to find them). Adding further info to the post is sometimes okay. I do this frequently, but I have editing privileges. Pragmatically speaking, I wouldn't try and do it through the review queue. But I very much hate this categorical advice not to edit anything but grammar or formatting that occasionally gets promulgated on Meta.

Comment: @NSNoob `Or is it valid for edits which add further info to the post?` Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339024/2227743

Comment: @CodyGray, thank you for clarifying. I will probably suggest an edit again at some point since the existing accepted answer is likely to remain where it is.

Comment: When you do, you should emphasize in your edit summary that you're correcting a minor technical inaccuracy, not just clarifying the post.

Comment: WOW, we moved from discussing to no end NAA's to "how to prevent content becoming stale/innacurate on the site", I see a improvement and the sentiment shifting toward a sane approach.

Comment: All these comments about the transience of comments have missed one thing -- active answerers usually will incorporate information left in comments, using their own writing style, which leads to a better (more self-consistent) end result.  Just because having the information in a comment long-term is not the desired result does not mean that leaving a comment is undesirable or even optional.  If the author ignores the comment, editing is appropriate.  And if they go into denial about their mistake, then a competing answer is needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd think that if an answer is active, the author could rewrite the correction to fit his voice or roll back the edit entirely. You get notified of edits to your post, after all... even proposed edits, iirc. Anyhow, this seems [relevant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339101/the-community-vs-the-domain-expert).

Comment: This is one of the many obvious problems that will continue to get worse from ignoring [reputation inflation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-to-do-about-rep-inflation).

Comment: *I'll gladly remove it* - Well, I doubt you would remove it *gladly* (Maybe *quickly*, or *angrily*, or even *insensibly*) if you were actually required to.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is this a reasonable channel to express this thinking?

Yes, meta can be a channel where you can challenge a decision made on main.

> Does my reasoning make sense, or have I misunderstood something about the process of editing existing answers?

Since we are a technical site, domain experts are important to us since they are able to fact check, correct and curate information which would allow SO to become a site of canonical high quality answers to programming questions. Your reasoning makes perfect sense and it's aligned with the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!

I'm sorry and worried about these kind of issues and [have proposed some changes to the system to allow experts to review what they can make sensible reviews about, using the already implemented filters on the queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575).

If I had time to investigate and verify your edit (I don't know base64 enough), I would have applied your edit by now. Lets hope someone knowledgeable can take upon the task.