# Swiftly make [swift 3] more explicit

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I peruse the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag most often, and recently I've become fed up with all of the users who are tagging their question as [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) just because their code is using [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3). Just by looking at the tag wiki for [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), we can see this shouldn't be the case:

> Use this tag only for questions directly related to changes in version 3 of Apple's Swift programming language. Use the tag [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) for more general language questions, or the tags [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa), [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) etc for questions about developing on Apple platforms.

Today alone I've had to edit multiple questions in the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag page just because they include [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) in them. Examples include: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42243167/revisions), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42249629/revisions) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42243538/revisions). To be fair, this issue isn't just limited to [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), but also saw the same problem with [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) today in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42243870/revisions).

Furthermore, it is not only new users who don't understand the purpose of this tag. Today I edited a question that had the [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) tag on it, deleting this tag, only to find out that 1. a >10k rep user added it in the first place and 2. they then re-added it afterwards. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42243821/revisions) I am talking about, and it clearly has nothing to do with the differences between Swift 3.x and previous versions of the language.

I understand this still isn't "a lot" of scenarios where this is happening but it is frustrating that many users don't know how to use this tag properly.

What would be the best way to make this tag more explicit? I understand that I can edit the tag wiki, but is there any more effective way? If not, can any more experienced tag editors give some advice on how to do this properly?

Comment: I wish I had better advice, but this is [a longstanding problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62684/159251) that's [not really fixable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285338/603977) without completely changing the system and culture of tagging. So: not really fixable.

Answer (score -8):

As for real - Swift tag basically can be used for Swift 1.0, when it had just appeared. Apple didn't call it, 1.0 ... generally saying, when we use comparison of programming languages e.g. Swift and Objective-C; Swift and C# of course mostly we can use tag "Swift".
For cases, when we obviously use code with Swift syntax - sometimes it is necessary to know what version of Swift had been used.